# How to add an alias to a kernel module?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I'd like to add an alias to a kernel module, e.g. make `nvidia-343` available as `nvidia` on Ubuntu 14.10 with Linux 3.18.1, so that it can be loaded under the alias name and so that the alias appear in the list of aliases in `modinfo`.

The current level of explanation of what a kernel module alias is in the manpages of `modprobe`, `modinfo`, `modinfo`, etc. is rather ridiculous because it is zero (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kmod/+bug/1405669 as well).

Adding a line in the form of `alias <name> <alias>` to `/etc/modprobe.conf` as described at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x44.html doesn't work (alias not listed in `modinfo` output) (I guess(!) these are the docs for 2.6.x anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you know all you need to know about module aliases. Adding that line in `/etc/modprobe.conf` does define an alias: doesn't it work when you run `modprobe <name>`? It doesn't work with `modinfo` because that program doesn't support aliases: they're a concept of the `modprobe` program, not of the lower-level tools like `insmod` and `modinfo`.

Comment: So the aliases of `modinfo` are different from the `modprobe` aliases? I see e.g. `alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*` in the output of `modinfo nvidia` (343.36).

Comment: @KarlRichter These are aliases stored in the module file itself (`nvidia.ko`). `modinfo` prints them out (and `depmod` writes them out to `/lib/modules/VERSION/modules.aliases` for `modprobe` to read), it doesn't read them in any configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Modprobe alias information is mostly stored in `/lib/modules/.../modules.alias` but if you want to add you own, you should probably put it in `/etc/modprobe.conf` or `/etc/modprobe.d/` or wherever your distro puts these sorts of things.